# Can't offset even with Extrude to Cursor

Tags: extrude

I am complete beginner to Blender, and trying to do extrude a basic obloid shape (a 'wall') at an angle, only along x and y axes (ie I'm in top orthographic view), keeping the wall exactly same thickness. I have seen someone doing this in youtube video, with the extrude to cursor tool, I think they previously set the 'Offset Even' option to do this, but Offset Even checkbox is not available on this tool I think?

So I turned Offset Even on with another tool, switched to this one, but it's not preserved setting.

See enclosed picture for what I want. Anyway, however I do it, I am not offsetting even, and the wall thickness varies with the angle I extrude to[image], not what I want :-(

I am using Blender 2.8. Thanks so much any ideas?

**Update**
I must be doing something wrong, tried @moonboots solution below, and still got walls different thickness when I extrude normals from planes with offset even. I guess can just copy walls and move round, but would be nice if possible make this work.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The edge loop created as you extrude is staying the same size, but when an angle is forced, the "wall" thickness changes based on the new angle.

The only way to correct for this is to rotate the edge loop as to go along.

Answer (score 1):

As Trey Harper says, it's normal, given that when you rotate your face the thickness decrease.

You could to do it with the *Shear* tool and some align view to face but it must be a bit tedious.

Maybe the best solution is to build a flat wall (or delete the thickness in your case as you've already built your wall), then select all, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> > *Extrude Faces Along Normal*s, extrude, and make sure that the *Offset Even* option is enabled in the *Operator* box to keep an even thickness.

[image]